# SMTP Settings Not working for Hotmail

Tags: java, networking, smtp

```
Username: xxxxx.@hotmail.com

Password: yyyyyyyy

Pop3: pop3.live.com  Port: 995 SSL: TRUE

SMTP: smtp.live.com  Port: 587 SSL: TRUE (Port: 25 also not working)
```

These are the details I gave: POP3 settings accepted and SMTP settings throw Exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

I got this Exception when I try to send a mail via Java Coding.

Can any one help me for correct SMTP settings which will works to send mail.

I have Send mail using Gmail and Yahoo.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you only use their incoming address. For outgoing to need to use a local/private/alternate SMTP server.

I check my incoming mail on a Live account through pop3.live.com and send out through mail.{myworkdomain}.com.au